# Getting an error while installing Python 3.4.4 in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, configure, python-install

While installing **Python 3.4.4** into Linux server by running `./configure` script and getting the following error:

```
checking for ensurepip... upgrade
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.pre.in'
```

I am trying to search but not getting that much information, could experts provide here their views, will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have removed the old python directory and followed the following steps which worked for me, thought to share with people here too.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.4.4.tgz
cd Python-3.4.4/
./configure
make altinstall
python3.4 -V
```